# Migrating from TFS to VSTS - Validation Licence Type Warning

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, azure-devops

We are planning a migration from an on-premises TFS instance to VSTS very shortly. Ahead of the migration, we run the pre-requisite Validation task and obtained the following warning from the TFS Migrator log report:

***"Unknown license type :VS Enterprise was found for user: S-1-5-21-1229257200-2060469098-nnnnnnnnn-nnnnnn. The user is assigned a default Basic license."***

[Info   @12:34:44.508] Validation completed 'Populate License Information' with result Warning, message Encountered invalid user licences and a default license was picked. Please look at the logs for more details.

Is this an issue of concern that will hinder our migration and how can this warning be resolved?

Would appreciate some advice or feedback on this. Thank you.

Comment: Are you running a dry run import with the official TFS Database Import Service.

Comment: Yes, the plan is to run a dry-run import.

Comment: If so, please see my reply below this will not hinder your migration. You could ignore the warning. You don't need to repeat a dry run import if users don't automatically get upgraded to use their Visual Studio Subscription in VSTS. As long as the work account gets linked correctly before or after the import then the user will automatically have their license upgraded on the next sign in.

Comment: Thanks @PatrickLu-MSFT

Answer (score 2):

According to the detail info. This should be a license issue. For a specific account which have VS Enterprise not detect by VSTS and VSTS assigned him a default Basic license. VSTS have **5 free users** which have default Basic license.

Based on the warning level and error message, this **will not hinder your migration.** After the migration finished, then you could deal with the particular account's license.  Visual Studio Subscription linking is something that happens outside of the scope of an import. Usually VSTS will auto detect Visual Studio Subscriptions after the user signed in.

You could take a look at below explanation from MSDN:

> TfsMigrator is unable to detect Visual Studio subscriptions (formerly
>   known as MSDN benefits) when generating the identity map log file.
>   Instead, it's recommended that you leverage the auto license upgrade
>   feature post import. **As long as a user's work account is linked
>   correctly, VSTS will automatically apply their Visual Studio
>   subscription benefits on their first login post import.** You're never
>   charged for licenses assigned during import, so this can be safely
>   handled post import.
>
> **You don't need to repeat a dry run import if users don't automatically get upgraded to use their Visual Studio Subscription in
>   VSTS. Visual Studio Subscription linking is something that happens
>   outside of the scope of an import.** As long as the work account gets
>   linked correctly before or after the import then the user will
>   automatically have their license upgraded on the next sign in. Once
>   they've been upgraded successfully, next time you import the user will
>   be upgraded automatically on the first sign in to the account.
>
> [*Source Link*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/articles/migration-import#visual-studio-subscriptions)

If the user still get the license issue, you could contact our [license support team](https://www.visualstudio.com/team-services/pricing/?rr=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com.sg%2F).